# Работа с текстовым файлом на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Текстовый файл содержит более 10000000 символов. Определите максимальную длину цепочки символов, среди которых каждые три соседних символа одинаковые.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
a = list(f.read())
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        if a[i-4] == a[i-3] == a[i-2] and a[i-1] == a[i] == a[i+1] and a[i+2] == a[i+3] == a[i+4]:
            count += 1
    except: pass
print(count)
```

Я не понял условие задачи, ответ получается слишком большой

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Пример бы, т.к. условие неоднозначное.

Comment: Вот что от вас требуется. Есть строка, например, ```111222233333```. В этом примере максимальная длина цепочки символов равна 5, потому что самая длинная цепочка это ```33333```. У вас задача найти самую длинную цепочку, а не посчитать количество таких цепочек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скажем, нашли вы такую цепочку достаточно длинную. Как она может выглядеть? Я имею в виду не всю строку, а только искомую цепочку. Для определённости первый символ `a`. Тогда три первых символа цепочки тоже `a` - цепочка начинается с `aaa`. А вторые три символа? Тоже `aaa`. Значит цепочка начинается с `aaaa`. И так далее - в самой длинной цепочке из условия все символы одинаковые: `aaa...a`.

Переформулируем: надо найти самую длинную цепочку одинаковых символов подряд.

```
import itertools


with open('file.txt') as f:
    a = f.read()

#     из длин выбираем максимальную
#     |   
#     |   из групп нам нужны            собираем группы
#     |   только их длины               одинаковых символов
#     |   |                             |
#     v   v                             v
#     --- -----------------             --------------------
print(max(sum(1 for _ in g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(a)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, условие я понял, задача прошла!